# SubSonic 3.0 two different Databases namespace Issue

Tags: database, namespaces, subsonic, schema

My question is simple, I have two databases with the same scehema, one is live database say DLive and other one is testbed say DTestBed....

However, I want to use the same database namespace for both database. How can I achieve that without changing namespace in my code all over? Sometimes you need to do builds for live and testbeds in the same day ! Its really hard to change big project namespaces everytime you build.

How can I just change the webconfig connection string and get it done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

STEP 1:
Open 'Setting.ttinclude' from your Subsonic project..

STEP 2:
Add new vairable beneath 'const string DatabaseName'..

```
const string DatabaseObjectName = "DatabaseObjectName";// This is the object that you use for calling Stored Procedures, Tables and etc...
```

like this;
    DatabaseObjectNameDB db = new DatabaseObjectNameDB();

STEP 3:
Now open 'ActiveRecord.tt', 'StoredProcedures.tt', 'Context.tt' files from your Subsonic project..

STEP 4:
Replace '<#=DatabaseName#>' with '<#=DatabaseObjectName#>' in above opened files...

STEP 5:
Now 'Run Custom Tools', by Righ-Click your Subsonic project...

Here you go... 
Problem solved!!

Regards,
Naeem

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SubSonic2 or three?

With SubSonic 3 it's as simple as this:

```
var db = new YourProductDB("connectionstringname");
var db = new YourProductDB("Server=localhost;Database=devdb;Uid=root;", "MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
```

for the first row you have to have both connection strings defined in your web.config/app.config